# Azure Linux VM Template - Parameter osProfile not allowed but without I can't connect

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager, azure-deployment, azure-rm-template

I created a VM manually in Azure then used the automation script to generate a template to use from Visual Studio for a deployment however when I try to deploy it everything else works bar the VM which complains about the osProfile parameter, If I remove the osProfile section the deployment works but creates a VM I have no way to login to, all the examples I find say the osProfile I have should be fine so I'm a bit stuck

The template attached only works when the osProfile is commented out and then you can't login to the VM

Appreciate any suggestions as I've tried all sorts and am stumped now!

This is the error when the osProfile is included:

```
08:58:16 - Template deployment returned the following errors:
08:58:16 - 08:58:15 - Resource Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines 'TheFaireyDevSolr' failed with message '{
08:58:16 -   "error": {
08:58:16 -     "code": "InvalidParameter",
08:58:16 -     "target": "osProfile",
08:58:16 -     "message": "Parameter 'osProfile' is not allowed."
08:58:16 -   }
08:58:16 - }'
```

I updated the Password parameter to something more complex that I know meets the min reqs.

Below is the template json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "adminUsername": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "User name for the Virtual Machine."
      }
    },
    "adminPassword": {
      "type": "securestring",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Password for the Virtual Machine."
      }
    },
    "disks_TheFaireyDevSolrDataDisk_name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "disks_TheFaireyDevSolrOsDisk_name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "virtualMachines_TheFaireyDevSolr_name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "networkInterfaces_thefaireydevsolr_ni_name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "networkSecurityGroups_TheFaireyDevSolr_nsg_name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "publicIPAddresses_TheFaireyDevSolr_ip_name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "virtualNetworks_TheFaireyDev_vnet_name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "storageAccounts_thefaireydevmainstorage_name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "extensions_Microsoft.Insights.VMDiagnosticsSettings_name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/disks",
      "name": "[parameters('disks_TheFaireyDevSolrDataDisk_name')]",
      "apiVersion": "2016-04-30-preview",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "scale": null,
      "properties": {
        "accountType": "Standard_LRS",
        "creationData": {
          "createOption": "Empty"
        },
        "diskSizeGB": 32
      },
      "dependsOn": []
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/disks",
      "name": "[parameters('disks_TheFaireyDevSolrOsDisk_name')]",
      "apiVersion": "2016-04-30-preview",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "scale": null,
      "properties": {
        "accountType": "Standard_LRS",
        "osType": "Linux",
        "creationData": {
          "createOption": "FromImage",
          "imageReference": {
            "id": "/Subscriptions/<YOUR SUBSCRIPTION ID>/Providers/Microsoft.Compute/Locations/uksouth/Publishers/Canonical/ArtifactTypes/VMImage/Offers/UbuntuServer/Skus/17.04/Versions/latest"
          }
        },
        "diskSizeGB": 30
      },
      "dependsOn": []
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
      "name": "[parameters('virtualMachines_TheFaireyDevSolr_name')]",
      "apiVersion": "2016-04-30-preview",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "scale": null,
      "properties": {
        "hardwareProfile": {
          "vmSize": "Standard_A1_v2"
        },
        "storageProfile": {
          "osDisk": {
            "osType": "Linux",
            "name": "[parameters('disks_TheFaireyDevSolrOSDisk_name')]",
            "createOption": "Attach",
            "caching": "ReadWrite",
            "managedDisk": {
              "storageAccountType": "Standard_LRS",
              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/disks', parameters('disks_TheFaireyDevSolrOsDisk_name'))]"
            },
            "diskSizeGB": 30
          },
          "dataDisks": [
            {
              "lun": 0,
              "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachines_TheFaireyDevSolr_name'),'DataDisk')]",
              "createOption": "Attach",
              "caching": "None",
              "managedDisk": {
                "storageAccountType": "Standard_LRS",
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/disks', parameters('disks_TheFaireyDevSolrDataDisk_name'))]"
              },
              "diskSizeGB": 32
            }
          ]
        },
        "osProfile": {
          "computerName": "[parameters('virtualMachines_TheFaireyDevSolr_name')]",
          "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
          "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
        },
        "networkProfile": {
          "networkInterfaces": [
            {
              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', parameters('networkInterfaces_thefaireydevsolr_ni_name'))]"
            }
          ]
        },
        "diagnosticsProfile": {
          "bootDiagnostics": {
            "enabled": true,
            "storageUri": "[concat('https', '://', parameters('storageAccounts_thefaireydevmainstorage_name'), '.blob.core.windows.net', '/')]"
          }
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/disks', parameters('disks_TheFaireyDevSolrOsDisk_name'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/disks', parameters('disks_TheFaireyDevSolrDataDisk_name'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', parameters('networkInterfaces_thefaireydevsolr_ni_name'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccounts_thefaireydevmainstorage_name'))]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
      "name": "[parameters('networkInterfaces_thefaireydevsolr_ni_name')]",
      "apiVersion": "2017-03-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "scale": null,
      "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "ipconfig1",
            "properties": {
              "privateIPAddress": "10.0.0.4",
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
              "publicIPAddress": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', parameters('publicIPAddresses_TheFaireyDevSolr_ip_name'))]"
              },
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworks_TheFaireyDev_vnet_name')), '/subnets/default')]"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "dnsSettings": {
          "dnsServers": []
        },
        "enableIPForwarding": false,
        "networkSecurityGroup": {
          "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('networkSecurityGroups_TheFaireyDevSolr_nsg_name'))]"
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', parameters('publicIPAddresses_TheFaireyDevSolr_ip_name'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworks_TheFaireyDev_vnet_name'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('networkSecurityGroups_TheFaireyDevSolr_nsg_name'))]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
      "name": "[parameters('networkSecurityGroups_TheFaireyDevSolr_nsg_name')]",
      "apiVersion": "2017-03-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "scale": null,
      "properties": {
        "securityRules": [
          {
            "name": "default-allow-ssh",
            "properties": {
              "protocol": "Tcp",
              "sourcePortRange": "*",
              "destinationPortRange": "22",
              "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
              "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
              "access": "Allow",
              "priority": 1000,
              "direction": "Inbound"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "dependsOn": []
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
      "name": "[parameters('publicIPAddresses_TheFaireyDevSolr_ip_name')]",
      "apiVersion": "2017-03-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "scale": null,
      "properties": {
        "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
        "idleTimeoutInMinutes": 4
      },
      "dependsOn": []
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
      "name": "[parameters('virtualNetworks_TheFaireyDev_vnet_name')]",
      "apiVersion": "2017-03-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "scale": null,
      "properties": {
        "addressSpace": {
          "addressPrefixes": [
            "10.0.0.0/24"
          ]
        },
        "subnets": [
          {
            "name": "default",
            "properties": {
              "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/24"
            }
          }
        ],
        "virtualNetworkPeerings": []
      },
      "dependsOn": []
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard_LRS",
        "tier": "Standard"
      },
      "kind": "Storage",
      "name": "[parameters('storageAccounts_thefaireydevmainstorage_name')]",
      "apiVersion": "2016-01-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {},
      "scale": null,
      "properties": {},
      "dependsOn": []
    },
    //{
    //  "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
    //  "name": "[parameters('extensions_Microsoft.Insights.VMDiagnosticsSettings_name')]",
    //  "apiVersion": "2016-04-30-preview",
    //  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    //  "scale": null,
    //  "properties": {
    //    "publisher": "Microsoft.OSTCExtensions",
    //    "type": "LinuxDiagnostic",
    //    "typeHandlerVersion": "2.3",
    //    "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
    //    "settings": {
    //      "xmlCfg": "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"
    //    },
    //    "protectedSettings": {}
    //  },
    //  "dependsOn": [
    //    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', parameters('virtualMachines_TheFaireyDevSolr_name'))]"
    //  ]
    //}
  ],
  "variables": {}
}
```

and the parameters json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "adminUsername": {
      "value": "thefairey"
    },
    "disks_TheFaireyDevSolrDataDisk_name": {
      "value": "TheFaireyDevSolrDataDisk"
    },
    "disks_TheFaireyDevSolrOsDisk_name": {
      "value": "TheFaireyDevSolrOsDisk"
    },
    "virtualMachines_TheFaireyDevSolr_name": {
      "value": "TheFaireyDevSolr"
    },
    "networkInterfaces_thefaireydevsolr_ni_name": {
      "value": "TheFaireyDevSolr-ni"
    },
    "networkSecurityGroups_TheFaireyDevSolr_nsg_name": {
      "value": "TheFaireyDevSolr-nsg"
    },
    "publicIPAddresses_TheFaireyDevSolr_ip_name": {
      "value": "TheFaireyDevSolr-ip"
    },
    "virtualNetworks_TheFaireyDev_vnet_name": {
      "value": "TheFaireyDev-vnet"
    },
    "storageAccounts_thefaireydevmainstorage_name": {
      "value": "thefaireydevmainstorage"
    },
    "extensions_Microsoft.Insights.VMDiagnosticsSettings_name": {
      "value": "TheFaireyDevSolr/Microsoft.Insights.VMDiagnosticsSettings"
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I started with a plain Ubuntu VM template from VS and started adding stuff and the problem regarding the osProfile starts happening as soon as I try to add a Managed Disk as the OS disk, I removed that but tried with a managed disk for the DataDisk and got the error "Addition of a managed disk to a VM with blob based disks is not supported"

Not sure if it helps but I believe the issue may be related to having a Managed Disk as the OS disk. Will continue to research and experiment!

Comment: we can't remove OSprofile, can you show the error message when you use this template to deploy VM?

Comment: Yeah what is the actual error and what is the value of the parameter you are passing in? I guess that isn't the actual password but make sure it meets the minimum password reqs

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT You can remove osProfile, the deployment works when it's commented out but it creates a VM that you have no way to connect to, which is obvious I guess as it has no login details assigned. If I include the osProfile .. updated the original to show the message

Comment: @EdElliott yeah I changed the password just in case it was a bad error message that was hiding an invalid password but no joy

Comment: @Simon To find the root cause, could you please post all your template?:)

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT I shall do shortly just want to sanitise it :-)

Comment: @Simon according to the error message, seems you have define parameter `osprofile`, can you find the parameter in your template?

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT - have included the full failing template and parameters file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok worked it out, the automation script I guess isn't quite up to speed with Managed Disks which is fair enough as they are in preview, when I ran it it created a separate resource for the OS Managed disk.

In order to have a managed disk as the OS disk you need to define the storageProfile as follows:

```
    "storageProfile": {
      "imageReference": {
        "publisher": "[variables('imagePublisher')]",
        "offer": "[variables('imageOffer')]",
        "sku": "[parameters('ubuntuOSVersion')]",
        "version": "latest"
      },
      "osDisk": {
        "osType": "Linux",
        "name": "YourOSDiskName",
        "createOption": "FromImage",
        "caching": "ReadWrite",
        "managedDisk": {
          "storageAccountType": "Standard_LRS"
        },
        "diskSizeGB": 32
      },
    }
```

The important thing is that you don't need to define the managed disk as a separate resource, it appears the VM creation handles creation of the Managed disk resource and you just need to specify the storageAccountType for the disk.

After that everything appears to work correctly.

Trying to Attach a previously defined Managed Disk based on an OS image and specifying the id parameter in the managedDisk settings in the VM doesn't appear to work.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

osProfile is required if the VHD is sysprepped & generalized - meaning when it starts you want to run through first time setup.  If the image is not generalized then you can't specify the osProfile (e.g. user/pass) because it already exists.

re: ManagedDisks - you can use an implicit disk or explicit.  If you wanted to use one of your own disk images your storageProfile would be:

```
  "storageProfile": {
    "imageReference": {
      "id": "[parameters('imageResourceId')]"
    }
  }
```

If you want to use your own disk (say, created from a snapshot) you would use:

```
    "storageProfile": {
      "osDisk": {
        "osType": "[parameters('osType')]",
        "name": "[parameters('managedOsDiskName')]",
        "createOption": "Attach",
        "managedDisk": {
          "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/disks', parameters('managedOsDiskName'))]"
        },
        "caching": "ReadWrite"
      }
    }
```

There are a lot of options available w/ managed disks... This [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/virtualmachines) isn't perfect but does help.

Comment: Thanks, I used that doc as best I could but as you say it's not perfect and the issue is it doesn't make it clear on what combinations work and I'm guessing as most parameters aren't mandatory that the validation stage passes most things even if they won't actually work.

Comment: Also my template above uses the second of the options you detail but that doesn't appear to work, using the "use your own disk" syntax fails when you include an osProfile and without it you have no way to login. However I'm not fully sure I understand the "sysprepped/generalized" aspect. The managed disk I create (and try to attach) in my template above based on an Ubuntu image; would that be sysprepped and generalized?

Comment: I think you need to use the Azure Linux agent - see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/intro-on-azure#virtual-machine-image-capture